# How could I redirect file name into counts by tab using one line commands in bash?

Tags: bash, sh

I have some files in fasta format and want to counts their reads and would like to have output in file names and their corresponding counts.

input file names:

```
1.fa
2.fa
3.fa
...
```

I tried:

```
for i in $(ls -t -v *.fa); do grep -c '>' $i > echo $i >> out.txt ; done
```

Problem:

It gives me out.txt but double file names and their counts by ':' separated. However, I need a tab and unique file names.

```
1.fa:7323580
1.fa:7323580
2.fa:5591179
2.fa:5591179
...
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Suggested solution

```
grep -c '>' *.fa | sed 's/:/'$'\t'/ > out.txt
```

The `$'\t\'` is a Bash-ism called [ANSI C Quoting](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#ANSI_002dC-Quoting).

#### Analysis of what went wrong

Your code is:

```
for i in $(ls -t -v *.fa); do grep -c '>' $i > echo $i >> out.txt ; done
```

It isn't a good idea to parse the output of the `ls` command.  However, if your file names are well behaved (roughly, in the [portable filename character set](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap03.html#tag_03_278), which is `[-A-Za-z._]`), you'll be reasonably OK.

Your `grep` command, though, is confused.  It is:

```
grep -c '>' $i > echo $i >> out.txt
```

That could be written more clearly as:

```
grep -c '>' $i $i > echo >> out.txt
```

This means 'count the number of lines containing `>` in `$i`, and then in `$i` again, and send the output first to a file `echo`, and then append to `out.txt`.  Since the append overrides the redirection, the file `echo` is empty.  You get the file name included in the output because there are two files to search; with only one file, you wouldn't get the file name too.  (One way to ensure you get file names with regular (not `-c` or `-l`) `grep` is to scan `/dev/null` too. Many versions of `grep` also provide options to get the name explicitly, but POSIX doesn't mandate one. BSD `grep` uses `-H`; so does GNU `grep`.)

So, that's why you got the double file names and entries in your output.

Comment: Thank you man....it was really simple but i made it complex with loop :P

anyway......sed 's/\:/\t/g' this works fine too.

Comment: Using `\t` in `sed` is problematic for portability, but so in a different way is `$'\t'`.  Use what works, and be wary if you need to migrate the code.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
for i in $(ls -t -v *.fa)
do
    c=$(grep -c '>' $i | awk -F: '{print $2}')
    echo "$i: $c" >> out.txt
done
```

Comment: Hi, thank you but its give me only file name because awk -F: '{print $2}' DO NOT STORE ANYTHING...
1. fa:    (i guess this is tab)

Comment: Ah, yes, if you're only greping one file, you won't need the awk section, just `c=$(grep -c '>' $i)` as this just evaluates to the count rather than the file name with the count separated by a colon. I tend to use `grep -c <some-text> <some-files> | awk -F: '$2>0 {print $0}'` to print out a summary of files where a match exists, together with the count.